# How to read user.config when a program deployed with Clickonce is run as an .exe file(not appref-ms file)

Tags: c#, vb.net, clickonce

When I run an exe file deployed with ClickOnce(not appref-ms file), how do .exe file view the value of user.config instead of looking at the app.exe.config file?

Because Actions that require administrator privileges, a program run by ClickOnce will try to run itself again as an administrator.

At this time, the program executed by the administrator has not read the stored setting value.

```
Try
            My.Settings.CurrentVersion = GetClickOnceVersion()
            My.Settings.Save()

            Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
            procInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            procInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath
            procInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
            procInfo.Verb = "runas"
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procInfo)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "MyProgram")
        End Try

        End
```

Comment: Please show what code you've tried and specifically where the issue is.

Comment: I've modified the question a bit more. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Set the Scope of the setting to "User"